# Javascript promises not waiting (using q, node, coffee)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, promise, q

I am trying to test my node module from a mocha test and I am having some difficulty understanding how promises are supposed to work.  I can't seem to get it to wait on the resolution of my promises.  Here is my coffeescript code

```
'use strict'
Q = require 'q'

exports.awesome = () ->
  headers = {"example" : "hello"}
  params = {"id" : "J123456789012345678"}

  console.log('response is' + JSON.stringify(@handleAPIRequest(headers,params)))
  console.log('awesome')
  'awesome'

exports.handleAPIRequest = (headers,params) ->
  @validateRequest(headers, params)
  .then(@loadFromDynamo)
  .then(@formatForAPI)
  .fail(@errorHandler)
  .done()

exports.validateRequest = (headers ,params) ->
  Q.Promise (resolve, reject, notify) ->
    console.log '1) valid Request'
    if headers['example'] == 'hello' && params["id"]
      resolve params["id"]
    else
      reject new Error('Invalid Request', 400)

exports.loadFromDynamo = (id) ->
  Q.Promise (resolve, reject, notify) ->
    console.log '2) load Request' + id
    resolve {key: 'value'}

exports.formatForAPI = (item) ->
  Q.Promise (resolve, reject, notify) ->
    console.log '3) formatforapi'
    resolve item

exports.errorHandler = (err) ->
  console.log('error ' + err)
  return err
```

Also here is the generated javascript:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var Q;
  Q = require('q');

  exports.awesome = function() {
    var headers, params;
    headers = {
      "example": "hello"
    };
    params = {
      "id": "J123456789012345678"
    };
    console.log('response is' + JSON.stringify(this.handleAPIRequest(headers, params)));
    console.log('awesome');
    return 'awesome';
  };

  exports.handleAPIRequest = function(headers, params) {
    return this.validateRequest(headers, params).then(this.loadFromDynamo).then(this.formatForAPI).fail(this.errorHandler).done();
  };

  exports.validateRequest = function(headers, params) {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
      console.log('1) valid Request');
      if (headers['example'] === 'hello' && params["id"]) {
        return resolve(params["id"]);
      } else {
        return reject(new Error('Invalid Request', 400));
      }
    });
  };

  exports.loadFromDynamo = function(id) {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
      console.log('2) load Request' + id);
      return resolve({
        key: 'value'
      });
    });
  };

  exports.formatForAPI = function(item) {
    return Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
      console.log('3) formatforapi');
      return resolve(item);
    });
  };

  exports.errorHandler = function(err) {
    console.log('error ' + err);
    return err;
  };

}).call(this);
```

And here is what is printed in the console:

```
1) valid Request
response is undefined
awesome
2) load RequestJ123456789012345678
3) formatforapi
```

I was expecting the result to read something like

```
1) valid Request
2) load RequestJ123456789012345678
3) formatforapi
response is item
awesome
```

Comment: `@handleAPIRequest(headers,params)` returns a promise. You can't call `JSON.stringify` on that. You need to use `.then(…)` again - the `awesome` method has to be asynchronous as well.

Comment: You're right I misunderstood the interaction between promises and non promise functions.